# tar --occurrence= option ignored?

Tags: linux, tar

Using GNU `tar` 1.26 on Linux, I'm looking for a way to stop processing after the N-th occurrence of a file in a `.tar` archive. This should work:

`tar --file=archive.tar --list --occurrence=1 filename`

But it doesn't work, for some reason. Besides: I know that `=1` is the default value here, but defined it here for a proper demonstration of what I'm trying to achive. What I've tried so far:

- `filename` = exact filename: Works perfectly, but then, why should I
  use this option when I can also define that just this file should be
  processed
- `filname` = something with wildcards, e.g. `*.pdf` processes all `*.pdf` files and seemingly ignores the `--occurrence=` option. I suspect that the wildcard deactivates `--occurrence=`
- Not using wildcards results in an "file can't be found" type of error
- Correct me if I'm wrong, but as far as I know there can't be more than on file with the exactly same name in a directory. My guess: This might work in combination with `--no-ignore-case`, but then… not?

**Question**: What would be the correct way to a) use the `--occurrence=` option – or b) process the, say, 2nd occurrence of a file?

Comment: You can get duplicate filenames by appending to an archive. That's where `--occurrence` is useful.

Comment: What distro are you using? I compiled tar 1.26 from source and it works OK. Using a test archive with **1/ 1/foo.pdf 2/ 2/foo.pdf 3/**. `./tar --file=/tmp/p.tar --list --occur=1 --wildcards '*.pdf'` yields `1/foo.pdf`. `./tar --file=/tmp/p.tar --list --occur=2 --wildcards '*.pdf'` yields `2/foo.pdf`. Could you tell us the exact pathnames within your archive of the first few occurrences of `filename`?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Quick answer: I'm using Crunchbang 11 - and found out today that it's closed down :( although I was able to get updates still. I'll try this on another machine with (possibly) another version and post the results later. Thanks for the effort!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't use `--occurrence` tar will extract the newest version of the file.

If you use it without `=` the oldest version will be extract, thus being the default value one is talking about, i.d. `1`.  Hence, `--occurrence=2` will cause the extraction of not the oldest version, but the next one.

The timestamp considered by my version of `tar` is the time listed by `t` option, which is the same with that listed by `ls -l`.